# Let $ \ p \in D \ $ and $ \ f(z)=\log(z-i) \ $ . Then show that $ \exists \ $ some $ \ \epsilon>0 $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \ \large D \ $ be a star shaped domain in the complex plane $ \ \mathbb{C} \ $ , which is not equal to whole complex plane .

(1) Let $ \ p \in D \ $  and $ \ f(z)=\log(z-i) \ $ .  Then show that $ \exists \  \  some \ \ \epsilon>0 \ $ such that

$ |f(z)-(f(p)+2 \pi i)| > \epsilon \ $  for all $ \ z \in D \ $.

**Answer:**

Here $ f(z)=\log(z-i) \ $ is analytic  everywhere except $ z=i \ $ and the half-line $ y=1 , \ x<0 \ $.

Since $ f \ $ is analytic , for some holomorphic function $ h(z) \ $, we can write

$ f(z)=e^{h(z)}  $

Thus,

$ |f(z)-(f(p)+2 \pi i) |=|e^{h(z)}-e^{h(p)}-2 \pi i| > |e^{h(z)}-e^{h(p)}|-|2 \pi i | \ =|e^{h(z)}-e^{h(p)}|-|2 \pi | \neq 0  $

Thus, $ |f(z)-(f(p)+2 \pi i)| \neq 0 \ \Rightarrow |f(z)-(f(p)+2 \pi i)| > \epsilon  , \ for \ some \ \epsilon>0 \ $